# Not able to mock AccountManager class in Kotlin which is using RxJava

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, rx-java2

This is my code in kotlin and RxJava, I am trying to test method by mocking accountManager class from Android but not able to mock it :( .

Creating variable like this:

```
private val accountManager:AccountManager= mock()
private val ACCOUNT_1 = Account("XXXXX", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
```

Injecting

```
userLocalDataSource = UserLocalDataSource(accountManager)
```

Method to test :

```
    override fun update(user: User, country: Country): Observable<User> {
    return Observable.create<User> {
        disposable ->
        val accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE)
        for (account in accounts) {
            if (disposable.isDisposed) break
            val userId = accountManager.getUserData(account, KEY_USER_ID)
            if (account.name == country.appName && user.id == userId) {
                accountManager.setUserData(account, KEY_USER_ID, user.id)
                accountManager.setUserData(account, KEY_USER_NAME, user.username)
                accountManager.setUserData(account, KEY_USER_FIRST_NAME, user.firstName)
                accountManager.setUserData(account, KEY_USER_LAST_NAME, user.lastName)
                accountManager.setUserData(account, KEY_USER_EMAIL, user.email)
                accountManager.setPassword(account, user.secret)
                accountManager.setUserData(account, KEY_USER_COUNTRY_ID, country.id.toString())
                accountManager.setUserData(account, KEY_USER_PHOTO, user.image?.url)
                disposable.onNext(user)
            }
        }
        disposable.onComplete()
    }
}
```

Unit testing method:

```
@Test
fun testUpdate(){
    Mockito.`when`(accountManager.getAccountsByType(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)).thenReturn(arrayOf(ACCOUNT_1))
    val result=userLocalDataSource.update(user,Country.GERMANY).blockingFirst()
    assertEquals("XXX",result?.username)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID and ACCOUNT_TYPE have same value??

Comment: Yes, both are same.

Comment: Please check if arrayOf(ACCOUNT_1) contains the proper value or not. Secondly can you verify if accountManager.getAccountsByType(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID) has been invoked or not during the method call userLocalDataSource.update(user,Country.GERMANY)

Comment: arrayOf(ACCOUNT_1) has correct value and accountManager.getAccountsByType(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID) is returning null value during call userLocalDataSource.update(user,Country.GERMANY), I am not sure why..and when I debug val account = Account(user.country.appName, ACCOUNT_TYPE) is also returning null .

Comment: What is the type of  BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID. Is it a string ?
Have you tried your code in application, does it work fine?

Comment: BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID is string type and its working fine in my application code . And I am not sure whether we should cover this type of test case with AndroidTestCase because it requires real context.